# How do I reference a variable for clearInterval in a different function?

Tags: javascript

I have a circular image I want to spin with a button click and stop with a different button click.

The spin() function works, but the stop() does not because the values die outside of the spin() function (correct me if I'm wrong). How should I solve this? I'm open to using the same button to spin and stop, but my if else statement produces the same result - spinning the image works, but I can't stop it.

Another unintended bug is that if I click on the spin button more than once, the spinning gets faster.

Here's my code:

```
var spinImage;  
function spin(){

        spinImage = document.getElementById('spinImage'), degree = 0;
        setInterval(function() {
        spinImage.style.transform = "rotate(" + ++degree + "deg)";}, 1);
}

function stop(){
        clearInterval(spinImage);
}
```

I need to stick to plain javascript and use the setInterval/clearInterval methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `id` when initializing setInterval (here store in spin variable). That variable will have reference to setInterval so that you can clear it up using `stop` function.

Another unintended bug (`faster spinning on consecutive clicks`) is due to the fact that, previous setInterval id is not cleared and new one is created. So, the number of times you click; you will have that many setIntervals. To avoid it, you need to clear up the existing id and then re-initialize with the new set interval.

Have fixed the code. Please see:

```
var spinImage;
var spin;  
function spin(){
    spinImage = document.getElementById('spinImage');
    degree = 0;
    if(spin) stop();
    spin = setInterval(function() {
        spinImage.style.transform = "rotate(" + ++degree + "deg)";
    }, 1);
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(spin);
}
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications

Answer (score 2):

the value you are looking for is the return value of `setInterval`:

```
var intervalId;
function spin() {
  var spinImage = document.getElementById('spinImage');
  var degree = 0;
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    spinImage.style.transform = 'rotate(' + ++degree + 'deg)';
  }, 1);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember the interval id, so that you can stop it.

```js
let intervalId = null;

function spin() {
  spinImage = document.getElementById('spinImage'), degree = 0;

  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    spinImage.style.transform = "rotate(" + ++degree + "deg)";
  }, 1);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

---

## ES6 Class

You can encapsulate this logic into a reusable class object i.e. `ImageSpinner`.

```js
const main = () => {
  const spinner = new ImageSpinner('#spinImage');

  addEventListeners('.btn-toggle', 'click', (e) => {
    spinner.toggle();
    let attr = `data-text-${spinner.isRunning() ? 'off' : 'on'}`;
    e.currentTarget.textContent = e.currentTarget.getAttribute(attr);
  });

  addEventListeners('.btn-reset', 'click', (e) => {
    spinner.reset();
    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn-toggle');
    btn.textContent = btn.getAttribute('data-text-on');
  });
}

class ImageSpinner {
  constructor(selector, rate) {
    /* @protected */ this.image = document.querySelector(selector);
    /* @protected */ this.rate = rate;
    /* @private   */ this.__intervalId = null;
    /* @private   */ this.__degree = 0;
  }
  /* @public */ isRunning() {
    return this.__intervalId != null;
  }
  /* @public */ reset() {
    if (this.isRunning()) this.stop();
    this.__degree = 0;
    this.__rotate();
  }
  /* @public */ start() {
    if (!this.isRunning()) {
      this.__intervalId = setInterval(() => { this.update() }, this.rate);
    } else {
      console.log('Already running...');
    }
  }
  /* @public */ stop() {
    if (this.isRunning()) {
      clearInterval(this.__intervalId);
      this.__intervalId = null;
    } else {
      console.log('Not currently running...');
    }
  }
  /* @public */ toggle() {
    this.isRunning() ? this.stop() : this.start();
  }
  /* @protected */ update() {
    this.__degree = (this.__degree + 1) % 360;
    this.__rotate();
  }
  /* @private */ __rotate() {
    this.image.style.transform = "rotate(" + this.__degree + "deg)";
  }
}

/*
 * Can either be an object of event handlers,
 * or an event name followed by a function.
 */
function addEventListeners(elementsOrSelector, events) {
  ((els) => els.forEach(el => 
    (typeof events === 'string' && arguments.length > 2)
      ? el.addEventListener(arguments[1], arguments[2])
      : Object.keys(events)
        .forEach(name => el.addEventListener(name, events[name]))))
  (Array.from((typeof elementsOrSelector === 'string')
    ? document.querySelectorAll(elementsOrSelector)
    : elementsOrSelector.entries
      ? elementsOrSelector
      : [elementsOrSelector]));
}

main(); // Execute main function
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  padding: 1.25em;
}

img {
  border: 2px dotted white;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  margin-top: 1.75em;
}

.btn-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<img id="spinImage" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ajlbNdBMWwA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAo/ND2LpoxaqAQ/photo.jpg?sz=96" alt="" width="96" height="96"/>
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn btn-toggle" data-text-on="Start" data-text-off="Pause">Start</button>
  <button class="btn btn-reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <head>
    <title>Spin</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button id='spinStart'>Start</button>
    <button id='spinStop'>Stop</button>

    <script>
      var spinning = false;
      var handle;
      var counter = 0;

      // Add click event listener to the start button
      window.document.getElementById('spinStart').addEventListener("click", start);
      // Add click event listener to the stop button
      window.document.getElementById('spinStop').addEventListener("click", stop);

      function start() {

        if(spinning === true) {
          console.log('spinning already')
          // Do nothing here as it's already spinning.
          spinning = !spinning;
        } 

        if(spinning === false) {
          // Not spinning here, so we have to init the setInterval
          handle = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(counter);
            counter++;
          }, 1000);
          spinning = !spinning;
        }
      }

      function stop() {
        //We only want to stop the spinner if it's actually spinning
        if(spinning === true){
          console.log('clearing the interval now!');
          clearInterval(handle);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Substitute your code as fits.